# What is the best way to copy a huge mercurial repository from one computer to another

Tags: mercurial, repository

We have a huge (around 10GB) mercurial repository. Pulling everything will take around 3-4 hours.
Complete repo is also available on my colleagues machine.
Is there a way to efficiently clone the repo from his to my machine?

---

My first thoughts were to ,

hg bundle the entire repo on his machine and copy it to usb stick.

create a clone with just 1(very first) changesets from the server

Then unbundle the entire repo on my machine.

---

bundle and unbundle take lots of time.

Wondering if there are better ways to do it.

Comment: It is not about Git, you should delete this tag

Comment: Hi! You should ask yourself, if you're using Hg correctly. A 10 GB repo indicates that you're storing binary files in it. Either store them elsewhere (for dependencies, use something like a Maven-proxy for Java projects) or use the Large File Extension or similar. See also: https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/HandlingLargeFiles

Comment: Can't you just copy the entire folder using an USB stick or over the network or something? There's nothing magical about a Mercurial repository, it's all just folders and files. Yes, there is some magic related to file links but that would not apply if you copy the files to a different computer.

Answer (score 1):

You can clone it right off the colleague's machine.  He can run "hg serve", which will report the http address to clone from, then you run "hg clone http://xxxxxx:8000" where `xxxxxx` is reported from the other machine.  You'll want a beefy network speed.  Use `--uncompressed` flag if you are on a local LAN.

Answer (score 0):

The speed dependends on a lot of factors.

Some things you could try:

- Use `hg serve` with or without compression (like mentioned by Mark, already)
- Use SSH with or without GZip compression (depending on the network speed).

Answer (score 0):

Simply copy the folder containing the working folder and `.hg` repository folder using any means possible:

- Copy it to a USB stick
- Copy it over the network

There is some magic related to local files when you clone to a different folder on the same machine in regards of file links, but this does not apply if you copy the repository to a completely different computer.

So assuming those 3-4 hours is not because your network is slow, you should be able to copy it using the normal OS tools.